# Data population from database as nested array object

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table structure as below in SQL Server database,

[image]

I want to populate the data from database something similar to JSON like as below:

```
id: 1
aname:  xyz
categories: bus
{
arnam: res
street: [s1,s2]
},
{
arnam: com
street: [c1,c2]
}
```

Can someone please guide me as to how I can do this in the database using normal SQL query or procedure.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not valid, but according to your table I think you want to know how to parse data from nested JSON with array of values with this structure:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
('{"id": 1, "aname":  "xyz",
   "categories": {
      "bus": [
         {"aname":  "res",
          "street": ["c1", "c2"]
          },
         {"aname":  "res",
          "street": ["s1", "s2"]
         }]
        }
    }'),
('{"id": 2, "aname":  "abc",
   "categories": {
      "bus": [
         {"aname":  "foo",
          "street": ["c1", "c2"]
          },
         {"aname":  "zoo",
          "street": ["s1", "s2"]
         }]
        }
    }')
) t1 ([json])
)SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [id]) AS RN,
    *
FROM cte AS e
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(e.[json]) WITH (
    [id] int '$.id',
    [aname] VARCHAR(100) '$.aname',
    [categories_jsn] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.categories.bus' AS JSON
) AS jsn
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([categories_jsn]) WITH (
    [street_arr] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.street' AS JSON,
    [aname_lvl2] VARCHAR(20) '$.aname'
) AS jsn2
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([street_arr]) WITH (
    [street] VARCHAR(20) '$'
)
```

Output:
[image]